# How to get struct name in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Let say I have a struct, `struct = %MyApp.MyModel{ filled_with_data: "true }`.

How can I get struct name (`MyApp.MyModel` in my case)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's stored in a field named `__struct__`, so `struct.__struct__ == MyApp.MyModel`.

Answer (score 28):

You can also get the struct name by pattern matching:

```
%name{} = struct
```

Comment: That is awesome, didn't know you could get it w/ pattern matching!

Comment: I like this because it does not rely on the `:__struct__` map key, which is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the name of the struct as a string without the "Elixir." prefix, but keeping any of your module prefixes you can do:

```
name = your_map.__struct__
       |> Module.split
       |> Enum.join(".")
```

Comment: For the equivalent of `your_map.__struct__` (where `your_map` is an `Ecto.Schema.t` struct), I didn't get the `Elixir.` prefix in the result just now in `iex`.

Answer (score 2):

Structs carry __struct__

field in them. So,

```
struct.__struct__
```

should do

Comment: @Dogbert was first!